# Javascript file in Mac for WebStorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I would like to debug with WebStorm but I do not know which `JavaScript file` location should I set.

Do you know? On official site I found this, but does not work.

[image]

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/running-and-debugging-node-js.html

And this is the project looks like:

[image]

Comment: do you have `bin/www` in `Portal` folder? if yes, what does the `www` file look like? `www` is a standard main file for apps created by [express-generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html), Webstorm doesn't throw any errors when specifying it as a *JavaScript file*. But if your project structure is different, you need specifying a valid path (related to chosen *Working directory*) to your application main .js file

Comment: I don't know WebStorm at all, but the text "JavaScript file:" suggests specifying the actual file you want it to run. "bin/www" sounds very much like a folder.

Answer (score 0):

How do you usually run the app? If there is an index.js inside the bin/www. You should mark that in the "Javascript file".

Comment: usually I just write `yarn start`